# PHP preg_replace second occurence of character

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I adjust my code below to replace the second » character using preg_replace?

```
$out = 'Home » Food » Fruit';
$out = preg_replace('/»/', 'Category:', $out, 1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But that replaces all occurences of ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only remove the second occurrence of a string, you need to match the first one, and then match *and capture* all text up to the second one, and then replace using a backreference.

Use

```
$out = 'Home » Food » Fruit';
$out = preg_replace('/(»[^»]*)»/', '$1Category:', $out, 1);
echo $out;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/dtinGC). The last `$limit` argument will have `preg_replace` only replace the first match.

**Details**:

- `(»[^»]*)` - Capturing group #1 matching

  - `»`  - a literal `»`
  - `[^»]*` - 0+ occurrences (due to `*` quantifier) of any chars other than `»`
- `»` - a literal `»`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Acvr5x/1).

A variation that is only supported in Boost/PCRE (and latest versions of Onigmo) and will also work for you:

```
/»[^»]*\K»/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Acvr5x/2). `\K` will discard all the text matched so far in the current iteration. so you will only have the closing chevron in the match to be replaced with your replacement string.

Comment: thanks but your code replaces all occurences of ». I need to replace only the second occurence of ».